# What is the best way to structure a configuration file for React?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, redux

I am building a website framework with React/Redux wherein the site's configuration is formatted in JSON and loaded into the Redux store. The configuration contains miscellaneous settings (like the name of the site and the Google Analytics ID), navigation structures (like the main nav, footer nav, and any additional navs), and a page index (which may contain up to 1000 pages).

The question: what is the best way to structure this configuration (specifically the page index) so that it can be parsed most efficiently?

There are two ways I can do this:

1. A single array of identical objects

   ```
   [
     {
       "id": 1,
       "url_slug": "about-us",
       "page_title": "About Us",
       "template": "about"
     },
     {
       "id": 2,
       "url_slug": "careers",
       "page_title": "Careers at Company Name",
       "template": "default"
     }
   ]
   ```

With this method, the data is nicely packaged in a predictable structure, however I need to parse through the array once (per page load) to find the index of the object I want to reference by url_slug.

2. An object with unique keys

   ```
   {
     "about-us": {
       "id": 1,
       "page_title": "About Us",
       "template": "about"
     },
     "careers": {
       "id": 2,
       "page_title": "Careers at Company Name",
       "template": "default"
     }
   }
   ```

With this method, I can easily reference which object I want based on its key, but with a large site it will result in a single object with hundreds of keys.

So, which is best for performance? Does it make a difference?

Comment: If you only need to access one object per page load, why are you sending "hundreds" of objects every time? Just send the one you need.

Comment: Have you had the opportunity to test it yourself?

Comment: @Jordan The object is loaded once per visit. The idea is that the application can react to various inputs immediately without calling additional information.

Comment: @maniak1982 No, I am still building the framework. Would like to know the best practices before building it out further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case there are no real advantages to using an array instead of an object. There's nothing inherently worse about having "a single object with hundreds of keys" than having a single array with hundreds of elements—except, perhaps, that those keys take up memory, but "hundreds" of keys will add up to kilobytes at most.

If the order of your objects is important, use an array. If you want random access (i.e. access by some unique key), use an object. (If order is important *and* you want random access, you'll need to do more work, but it doesn't looks like that's the case.)